# Why textview is not showing emojis on first time?

Tags: android, textview, emoji

Basically I'm getting the text from server and setting that to the `textview` without any problem . But the emojis are not being set properly on the first time but when I am updating the `textView` means invalidating it and getting the text again from server it's showing `emojis` properly . I also tried to use the `com.android.support:support-emoji-bundled:27.1.1` and some other libs but the problem is remaining the same . Can anyone please help me to fix this quirky issue ?

The `textView` is a part of `recyclerview` so I'm sending the text to the adapter class and setting that on `textView` inside `onBindViewHolder()` method.

The text is typically like `☺️`

Comment: It is difficult to give you an answer when you do not provide any code. How have you define the `TextView` in the layout file? Where (in which method) do you initialize the `TextView`?  What does a sample of the "text" look like, that you wish to display? Where and how are you "invalidating the `TextView`?

Comment: @Barns I apologize that I hadn't given the details but now please have a look at my question